# Statically referencing values in doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Often I need to lookup certain rows from the database, a simplistic example would be creating a new user and referencing 'Mr' from a table defining possible salutations.

Peppering the code with static references to a database value would seem really bad, i.e.:

`$em->getRepository('Salutations')->findOneBy(array('name' => 'Mr'));`

So instead I create a constant in the Salutations entity, i.e.:

`$em->getRepository('Salutations')->findOneBy(array('name' => Salutations::MR);`

This at least limits some database changes to only affecting one file but does not seem ideal. Is there a better way to statically reference database values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constants are great for this, if you need to save time typing and avoid typos.

When I need to control used values, e.g. not to allow "Misses", I use `ManyToOne` association to another entity, e.g. `Salutation`.